# SQL wildcard selection

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to look for tax return from the database at the moment, so I added where clause like below

```
WHERE  (memo LIKE '%TAX%'AND memo NOT LIKE '%TAXI%')
OR memo NOT LIKE '%IRS%'
OR memo LIKE '%BOFI RAC%'
OR memo LIKE '%EPS RFND%'
OR memo LIKE '%REPUBLIC TRS RT FED%'
OR memo LIKE '%TA PAYMENT%'
OR memo LIKE '%JTHF-EA JTHF ADV%'
OR memo LIKE '%REFUND ADVANTAGE ELEC REFND%'
OR memo LIKE '%TAX PRODUCTS PE3%'
```

However, there is a result `PAYPAL TRANSFER` popped out.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: `'PAYPAL TRANSFER'` (as with many other memos, I assume) does not contain "IRS" so it meets your conditions.

Comment: is there anyway to exclude IRS and not letting unrelated results popped out? @GordonLinoff

Comment: `where memo like any(array['%TAX%','%BOFI RAC%','%EPS RFND%',...]) and memo not like all(array['%TAXI%','%IRS%'])`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
WHERE (memo NOT LIKE '%IRS%' AND
       (memo LIKE '%TAX%'AND memo NOT LIKE '%TAXI%') OR
        memo LIKE '%BOFI RAC%' OR
        memo LIKE '%EPS RFND%' OR
        memo LIKE '%REPUBLIC TRS RT FED%' OR
        memo LIKE '%TA PAYMENT%' OR
        memo LIKE '%JTHF-EA JTHF ADV%' OR
        memo LIKE '%REFUND ADVANTAGE ELEC REFND%' OR
        memo LIKE '%TAX PRODUCTS PE3%'
       )
      )
```